# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04 using an iso file only?

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu `22.04 LTS` to Ubuntu `23.04` using an `iso` file only.
I don't want to redownload any thing because my ISP gives me very limited amount of data and it's expensive.
I would have no problem to reinstall the system from the iso file if I can somehow save my files and apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way)   Do note (*see my answer*) that it notes your installed apps before erasing system directories, thus the *manually installed* apps you had installed are re-downloaded IF THEY AREN'T ON THE ISO you install from, thus internet is required & many apps maybe downloaded (*as they'll need upgrading too; unless snap packages*)

Comment: From ISO? No. https://askubuntu.com/a/1429801/925128, https://askubuntu.com/a/1219470/925128. I would simply reinstall after saving data, then try to see if the home folder was kept or not. As said under here https://askubuntu.com/q/1406798/925128: `choose "other" option and don't format /home partition if it is separate from /, or don't format /`. But I have never tried that. (As said in other comment, apps won't be kept/reinstalled without internet). I would create a new partition and install there the new system, and then delete old one after migrating files from there.

Comment: Without internet I don't see how you could keep your apps. If you really need them and you don't have internet, you better DON'T upgrade. What's wrong with 22.04? - Or if you really need 23.04 and your apps, install 23.04 in a new partition and use both systems in multi-boot until you get better internet.

Comment: FYI:  I perform *package upgrades* on a number of systems via re-installs as it accomplishes two goals; upgrades packages (*I use daily ISOs for the re-install*) at the same time as completing a QA-test with the daily... My checks ensure the *manually installed* packages got re-installed, my data files weren't touched etc.. When a releases reaches EOL (*excluding my primary box*) I use this same method to move the system to a newer release I don't currently have (*usually the next development*) thus perform a *skip* of release.. eg. when 21.10 reached EOL I re-installed and made it 22.10

Comment: ...  thus I'm doing what you want, however the re-install cannot install apps it does not have on the ISO itself.. thus a re-download of all *manually installed* packages not found on the ISO is required.. I don't see any way around that, as it's how the REPAIR or *non-destructive* RE-INSTALL works & ensures everything works (*deb* packages are built for a specific release; if you change release you need new packages or you'll have segfaults due to ABI/API alignment issues). My prior answer tried to detail this (*I have most luck with this with flavors which have universe enabled by default*)

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04 using an ISO file.

- Create a Live install of 23.04 on your hard drive similar to: https://askubuntu.com/a/1251782/43926
- The GRUB menuentry is a little different for 23.4 than for 22.04, Use:

  ```
    menuentry "Try or Install ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64" {

    loopback loop /ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash locale=en_US bootkbd=us console-setup/layoutcode=us noeject --
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
    }
  ```

Boot the new ISO toram, Install Ubuntu 23.04 in free space.